# Sort WordPress post by Likes (ZillaLikes)

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I am implementing this plugin ZillaLikes http://www.themezilla.com/plugins/zillalikes/ which is great plugin allows people to 'love' my posts. I want to be able to now sort by those that are liked.

I have read through the documentation of sorting wordpress posts which is fine but cant work out how to do it with the associated likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this. But it should be possible to order by meta_key `_zilla_likes`

```
new WP_Query( array( 
  'meta_key' => '_zilla_likes',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, does zilla likes add meta data to each post then without the requirement to join tables?

Comment: It should add that to all posts that are liked. WP_Query takes care of the joining